# Mongoose reverse order of some elements picked out of entire list

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Currenty in Messages collection, I have have items like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ... 20].

If I code as following:

```
let order = "desc";
let sortBy = "_id";
const messages = await Message.find({ channel: channelID })
      .sort([[sortBy, order]])
```

Then "const messages" gets something like `[20,19,18,17,16].`

But I want it to be `[16,17,18,19,20]` after receiving from mongoose find function, without manually reverse this array.

I tried to set `let order = "asc";` but it then gives me `[1,2,3,4,5]`

How do I get `[16,17,18,19,20]` directly from mongoose query without manually reverse the order?

Comment: You should pass a String or Object as parameters. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct MongoDB syntax would be

```js
db.Message.find({ channel: channelID })
      .sort({ "_id": 1 })
```

So in JS

```js
const messages = await Message.find({ channel: channelID })
      .sort({ "_id", 1})
```

Or if you want to keep `_id` and 1 out of the query

```js
const order = 1;
const sortBy = "_id";

const orderQuery = {};
orderQuery[sortBy] = order ;

const messages = await Message.find({ channel: channelID })
      .sort(orderQuery)
```

Any issue let me know